# Somebody did something like a MindMap with flutter or Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Somebody did something like this image?

I would like to create links like image is showing.

I'm new with flutter and I tried "GraphView" but I can't customize it.

I saw TreeView, but doesn't work for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make this design using the GraphView package
[GraphView pub dev](https://pub.dev/packages/graphview)!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34502549)